# Draw a square from cursor center

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Currently I have a canvas where you can draw a square with your cursor like paint.net. As you drag your cursor it will create a square starting from the left corner. I wish for it to start at the center of the square instead. Is it possible to achieve this with `rect` ?

The code below draws a square starting from the left corner where `mouseCoords` is the starting point where your cursor started dragging and `currentMouse` is the location where you have dragged to.

```
//create rectangle starting from left corner
canvas.getContext('2d').rect(
  mouseCoords.x,
  mouseCoords.y,
  currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x,
  currentMouse.y - mouseCoords.y
);
```

Comment: Why not offset the starting position of the square to centre it around the starting position?  Unless I have missed a hidden complexity

Comment: I was trying that without any succes by pushing the starting point further away like so: ```mouseCoords.x - (currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x)``` (this being the first parameter for .rect. Same would be for Y). This would only result in drawing in the opposite direction

Comment: I found the solution, i forgot to multiply the width and height. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `mouseCoords.x` and `mouseCoords.y` are the center, then `currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x` and `currentMouse.y - mouseCoords.y` will be half the width and half the height, respectively. With that in mind it should be straightforward; the `x` coordinate will be `mouseCoords.x - (currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x)` which is `2 * mouseCoords.x - currentMouse.x`, the same goes for the `y` coordinate:

```
canvas.getContext('2d').rect(
  2 * mouseCoords.x - currentMouse.x,
  2 * mouseCoords.y - currentMouse.y,
  2 * (currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x),
  2 * (currentMouse.y - mouseCoords.y)
);
```

It's more clearer if you use variables that describe the values:

```
let halfWidth = currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x;
let halfHeight = currentMouse.y - mouseCoords.y;

canvas.getContext('2d').rect(
  mouseCoords.x - halfWidth,
  mouseCoords.y - halfHeight,
  2 * halfWidth,
  2 * halfHeight
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I made a mistake where I forgot to multiply the width and height.

```
context.rect(
  mouseCoords.x - (currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x),
  mouseCoords.y - (currentMouse.y - mouseCoords.y),
  (currentMouse.x - mouseCoords.x) * 2,
  (currentMouse.y - mouseCoords.y) * 2
);
```